# XCUIT-Swift-How to tap only on visible elements

Tags: ios, swift, automation, xcuitest

I want to tap "Next" button in my view

`lazy var Next = app.butons["Next"] Next.tap()`

I am getting below error

> Failed to get matching snapshot: Multiple matching elements found for <XCUIElementQuery: 0x280b0d4a0>.

Comment: try this  lazy var Next = app.butons["Next"].firstMatch.tap()

Answer (score 3):

Ignoring typos, what XCTest is telling you is that multiple things match what you're trying to identify. It would be helpful to know which one you're targeting specifically, but you could blindly try to tap the first:

```
app.buttons["Next"].firstMatch.tap()
```

If you need to get the 2nd you'll have to manipulate the array of matches and grab the element at index 1 (0 is the first, which is cheaper to get using the previous code):

```
app.buttons["Next"].element(boundBy: 1).tap()
```

I find getting the 2nd or last matches to be things I do often so I extend `XCUIElementQuery` with computed properties `var secondMatch` and `var lastMatch`, where `secondMatch` returns the above element and `lastMatch` is the following:

```
extension XCUIElementQuery {
  var lastMatch: XCUIElement {
    return self.element(boundBy: self.count - 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: I get an error `Value of type 'XCUIElement' has no member 'element'`

Comment: It is telling you a fact :) You've typed something wrong. You're asking an XCUIElement to return a property of `.element` when it _is_ one. Your object needs to be of type `XCUIElementQuery`. Feel free to open a new question with more detail.

Comment: I typed exactly what you're showing in your answer: `app.buttons["my button"].element(boundBy: 1).tap()`, and I got the above error. What I'm trying to say is: there is an error in your answer. I was able to find the correct answer elsewhere, don't remember where though.

Comment: What is the correct code?

Comment: Here is the answer that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39449443/11004423 It shows that you need to use `app.buttons.matchingIdentifier("my_button").element(boundBy: 1).tap()`. That is what worked for me.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. That's a very old way to write an XCUIElementQuery. It should function exactly the same.

Comment: You legneds! I have exactly the same problem, same solution. Wonder what it is...